# PySide: QAbstractItemModel - access QLineEdit of an item

Tags: python, pyside, qlineedit, qabstractitemmodel

Is there any way to access the QLineEdit of an Item in a QAbstractItemModel? I want to auto focus that when a new Item is added to the model.

EDIT: I have a simplified version of my code only focusing on the QTreeView.

main.py:

```
import sys
from PySide import QtGui
from editable_tree import EditableTreeView


def main():
    pm_app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    pm_app.setStyle('plastique')
    pm_form = EditableTreeView()

    pm_form.show()
    pm_app.exec_()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

editable_tree.py:

```
from PySide import QtGui
from PySide import QtCore
import os
import editable_tree_ui    

class TreeItem(object):
    def __init__(self, _name, _parent=None):
        """
        :param _name: str
        :param _parent: TreeItem
        """
        self._name = _name
        self._children = []
        self._parent = _parent

        # if _parent is not None:
        #     _parent.add_child(self)

    def name(self):
        """
        :return: str
        """
        return self._name

    def set_name(self, name):
        """
        :param name: str
        :return: str
        """
        self._name = name

    def child(self, row):
        """
        :param row: int
        :return: TreeItem
        """
        return self._children[row]

    def child_count(self):
        """
        :return: list
        """
        return len(self._children)

    def parent(self):
        """
        :return: TreeItem
        """
        return self._parent

    def row(self):
        """
        :return: QModelIndex
        """
        if self._parent is not None:
            return self._parent._children.index(self)

    def add_child(self, child):
        """
        :param child: TreeItem
        """
        self._children.append(child)

    def insert_child(self, position, child):
        """
        :param position: int
        :param child: TreeItem
        :return: bool
        """
        if position < 0 or position > len(self._children):
            return False

        self._children.insert(position, child)
        child._parent = self
        return True

    def remove_child(self, position):
        """
        :param position: int
        :return: bool
        """
        if position < 0 or position > len(self._children):
            return False

        child = self._children.pop(position)
        child._parent = None

        return True

    def log(self, tab_level=-1):
        """
        :param tab_level: int
        :return: str
        """
        output = ""
        tab_level += 1

        for i in range(tab_level):
            output += "\t"

        output += "|------" + self._name + "\n"

        for child in self._children:
            output += child.log(tab_level)

        tab_level -= 1
        output += "\n"

        return output

    def __repr__(self):
        return self.log()


class TreeModel(QtCore.QAbstractItemModel):
    def __init__(self, _data, _parent=None):
        """
        :param _data: dict
        :param _parent: TreeItem
        """
        super(TreeModel, self).__init__(_parent)

        self._data = _data
        self.root_item = TreeItem('ROOT')

        self.setup_model_data(self._data)

    def rowCount(self, parent):
        """
        :param parent: QModelIndex
        :return: int
        """
        if not parent.isValid():
            parent_item = self.root_item
        else:
            parent_item = parent.internalPointer()

        return parent_item.child_count()

    def columnCount(self, parent):
        """
        :param parent: QModelIndex
        :return: int
        """
        return 1

    def data(self, index, role):
        """
        :param index: QModelIndex
        :param role: int
        :return: QString
        """
        if not index.isValid():
            return None

        item = index.internalPointer()

        if role == QtCore.Qt.DisplayRole or role == QtCore.Qt.EditRole:
            if index.column() == 0:
                return item.name()

    def setData(self, index, value, role=QtCore.Qt.EditRole):
        """
        :param index: QModelIndex
        :param value: QVariant
        :param role: int (flag)
        :return: bool
        """
        if index.isValid():
            if role == QtCore.Qt.EditRole:
                item = index.internalPointer()
                item.set_name(value)
                self.dataChanged.emit(index, index)

                return True
        return False

    def headerData(self, section, orientation, role):
        """
        :param section: int
        :param orientation:  Qt.Orientation
        :param role: int
        :return: QString
        """
        if role == QtCore.Qt.DisplayRole:
            if section == 0:
                return self.root_item.name()
            else:
                return "Typeinfo"

    def flags(self, index):
        """
        :param index: QModelIndex
        :return: int (flag)
        """
        return QtCore.Qt.ItemIsEnabled | QtCore.Qt.ItemIsSelectable | QtCore.Qt.ItemIsEditable

    def parent(self, index):
        """
        Should return the parent of the item with the given QModelIndex

        :param index: QModelIndex
        :return: QModelIndex
        """
        item = self.get_item(index)
        parent_item = item.parent()

        if parent_item == self.root_item:
            return QtCore.QModelIndex()

        return self.createIndex(parent_item.row(), 0, parent_item)

    def index(self, row, column, parent):
        """
        Should return a QModelIndex that corresponds to the given row, column and parent item

        :param row: int
        :param column: int
        :param parent: QModelIndex
        :return: QModelIndex
        """
        parent_item = self.get_item(parent)

        child_item = parent_item.child(row)

        if child_item:
            return self.createIndex(row, column, child_item)
        else:
            return QtCore.QModelIndex()

    def get_item(self, index):
        """
        :param index: QModelIndex
        :return: TreeItem
        """
        if index.isValid():
            item = index.internalPointer()
            if item:
                return item

        return self.root_item

    def insertRows(self, position, rows, parent=QtCore.QModelIndex()):
        """
        :param position: int
        :param rows: int
        :param parent: QModelIndex
        :return: bool
        """
        parent_item = self.get_item(parent)
        success = False

        self.beginInsertRows(parent, position, position + rows - 1)

        for row in range(rows):
            child_count = parent_item.child_count()
            child_item = TreeItem("untitled" + str(child_count))
            success = parent_item.insert_child(position, child_item)

        self.endInsertRows()

        return success

    def removeRows(self, position, rows, parent=QtCore.QModelIndex()):
        """
        :param position: int
        :param rows: int
        :param parent: QModelIndex
        :return: bool
        """
        parent_item = self.get_item(parent)
        success = False

        self.beginRemoveRows(parent, position, position + rows - 1)

        for row in range(rows):
            success = parent_item.remove_child(position)

        self.endRemoveRows()

        return success

    def setup_model_data(self, _data, _parent=None):
        """
        Setup TreeView structure extracted from _data

        :param _data: dict
        :param _parent: TreeItem
        """
        if _parent is None:
            _parent = self.root_item

        for key, value in sorted(_data.iteritems()):
            if isinstance(value, dict):
                _item = TreeItem(key, _parent)
                _parent.add_child(_item)
                self.setup_model_data(value, _item)


class EditableTreeView(QtGui.QMainWindow, editable_tree_ui.Ui_MainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        """
        :param parent: TreeItem
        """
        super(EditableTreeView, self).__init__(parent)

        self.setupUi(self)

        self.template_path = r'C:\Users\gwuest\Downloads\PROJECT_TEMPLATE'
        self.target_path = ''

        self.template = self.get_directory_structure(self.template_path)

        model = TreeModel(self.template)

        self.treeView.setModel(model)

    def get_directory_structure(self, _path):
        """
        Creates a nested dictionary that represents the folder structure of _path

        :param _path: str
        :return: dict
        """
        structure = {}
        _path = _path.rstrip(os.sep)
        start = _path.rfind(os.sep) + 1

        for path, dirs, files in os.walk(_path):
            folders = path[start:].split(os.sep)
            subdir = dict.fromkeys(files)
            parent = reduce(dict.get, folders[:-1], structure)
            parent[folders[-1]] = subdir

        return structure
```

editable_tree_ui.py:

```
from PySide import QtCore, QtGui

class Ui_MainWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
        MainWindow.resize(800, 600)
        self.centralwidget = QtGui.QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
        self.horizontalLayout = QtGui.QHBoxLayout(self.centralwidget)
        self.horizontalLayout.setObjectName("horizontalLayout")
        self.treeView = QtGui.QTreeView(self.centralwidget)
        self.treeView.setObjectName("treeView")
        self.horizontalLayout.addWidget(self.treeView)
        self.verticalLayout = QtGui.QVBoxLayout()
        self.verticalLayout.setObjectName("verticalLayout")
        self.btn_open_template = QtGui.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.btn_open_template.setObjectName("btn_open_template")
        self.verticalLayout.addWidget(self.btn_open_template)
        self.btn_open_target = QtGui.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.btn_open_target.setObjectName("btn_open_target")
        self.verticalLayout.addWidget(self.btn_open_target)
        spacerItem = QtGui.QSpacerItem(20, 40, QtGui.QSizePolicy.Minimum, QtGui.QSizePolicy.Expanding)
        self.verticalLayout.addItem(spacerItem)
        self.horizontalLayout.addLayout(self.verticalLayout)
        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.menubar = QtGui.QMenuBar(MainWindow)
        self.menubar.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 800, 21))
        self.menubar.setObjectName("menubar")
        MainWindow.setMenuBar(self.menubar)
        self.statusbar = QtGui.QStatusBar(MainWindow)
        self.statusbar.setObjectName("statusbar")
        MainWindow.setStatusBar(self.statusbar)

        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)

    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle(QtGui.QApplication.translate("MainWindow", "MainWindow", None, QtGui.QApplication.UnicodeUTF8))
        self.btn_open_template.setText(QtGui.QApplication.translate("MainWindow", "Template", None, QtGui.QApplication.UnicodeUTF8))
        self.btn_open_target.setText(QtGui.QApplication.translate("MainWindow", "Server", None, QtGui.QApplication.UnicodeUTF8))
```

So everytime i add an item manually i want the QLineEdit to be auto focused to the user can edit the name without having to double click the newly generated item.

EDIT: a manual add_child would look like this

```
class MyView(QtWidgets.QMainWindow, editable_tree_ui.Ui_MainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(MyView, self).__init__(parent)
        self.setupUi(self)

        self.btn_open_template.clicked.connect(self.add_child)

    def add_child(self):
        """
        insert child folder to selected folder
        """
        index = self.treeView.selectionModel().currentIndex()
        model = self.treeView.model()

        selected_folder = index.internalPointer()

        _child = TreeItem('New Folder', selected_folder)
        selected_folder.add_child(_child)
        model.layoutChanged.emit()
```

Comment: What QLineEdit are you referring to?

Comment: How do you add a new item manually ?, I see that your project analyzes a directory and loads it into the QTreeView through a model but I do not see how to add an item manually.

Comment: i removed self.test because it was just some testing code, not relevant to the issue at hand. In this example no manual adding is implemented...i did not think it was relevant.

Comment: you say: *So everytime i add an item manually*, you can explain that phrase, for example when I have tested your code I have changed the path of template_path this loads all the files generating n items, to which of the items do you mean?

Comment: I see that you have added that code but how do you invoke it? What class does the add_child method belong to? I got confused if I do not see it in your main code

Comment: i edited my question...i have an add_child method were i select any item (including the visible root) and add a child to it...after adding that i would have the text focused (like when double clicking an editable tree item) for convinient editing of that text

Comment: edited MyView again to make things a bit clearer...i just used the btn_open_template button to trigger add_child

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To make an item editable you must use the QModelIndex but in your case you only have the TreeItem so I have implemented a method that returns the QModelIndex associated with the TreeItem:

```
class TreeModel(QtCore.QAbstractItemModel):
    # ...
    def indexFromItem(self, item):
        if item is None or item == self.root_item:
            return QtCore.QModelIndex()
        if item.parent() is None:
            return QtCore.QModelIndex()
        pos = []
        while item.parent() is not None:
            pos.append(item.row())
            item = item.parent()
        ix = QtCore.QModelIndex()
        for r in reversed(pos):
            ix = self.index(r, 0, ix)
        return ix
```

After obtaining the `QModelIndex` you must expand the item and use the edit() method.

```
class EditableTreeView(QtGui.QMainWindow, editable_tree_ui.Ui_MainWindow):
    # ...
    def add_child(self):
        """
        insert child folder to selected folder
        """
        index = self.treeView.selectionModel().currentIndex()
        model = self.treeView.model()
        selected_folder = model.get_item(index)

        _child = TreeItem('New Folder', selected_folder)
        selected_folder.add_child(_child)
        # model.layoutChanged.emit()   
        self.treeView.expand(index)
        ix_child = model.indexFromItem(_child)
        self.treeView.setCurrentIndex(ix_child)
        self.treeView.edit(ix_child)
```